# WPF: Editable ComboBox that drops up?

Tags: wpf, combobox

Im trying to create a ComboBox thats both editable and drops up instead of down. The menu should also open when pressing the up-arrow-key (down by default).

I have tried modifying the default ControlTemplate for ComboBox but it doesn't seem to have any support for IsEditable?

Answer (score 2):

The default `ControlTemplate` is not for the `IsEditable = true` variety, but the style contains a trigger that changes it when IsEditable is set:

```
<Style.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
        <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource TextBoxBorder}"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.WindowBrushKey}}"/>
        <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
        <Setter Property="Padding" Value="3"/>
        <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
    </Trigger>
</Style.Triggers>
```

It changes it to another `ControlTemplate` where the relevant part is the popup:

```
<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" 
       AllowsTransparency="true" 
       Grid.ColumnSpan="2" 
       IsOpen="{Binding IsDropDownOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}" PopupAnimation="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemParameters.ComboBoxPopupAnimationKey}}" 
       Placement="Bottom">
...
</Popup>
```

I think you should just be able to change the `Placement` property to `Top`.