# How to scroll up combobox?

Tags: wpf, xaml

How to scroll up combobox?

My combobox looks like:

[image]

But I need something like:

[image]

My xaml:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="pages" IsEditable="False" IsReadOnly="True" Text="Mail version" 
  Height="24" Margin="280,0,163.6,11.4"  HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
  VerticalAlignment="Bottom"  Width="70" SelectionChanged="comboBox_SelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True">-page-</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="1"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="2"/>
    <ComboBoxItem Content="3"/>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: If you want it exactly like that (I'm, guessing not) add a 180° RotateTransform, for the sensible alternative you need to overerride/change the controltemplate so the popup placementposition is `Top` (e.g. like described here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/cbdb815b-edf5-4687-9c83-2bb384d7474e/how-to-open-combo-box-in-up-side-manner-in-wpf?forum=wpf)

Comment: No I just need it to scroll up, that's it. no need 180

Comment: I know, that part was a joke - for the actual solution, try the link.

Comment: Here is another example: [WPF: Editable ComboBox that drops up?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6063712/wpf-editable-combobox-that-drops-up)

Comment: Placement="Top" works, I just tried it.

Comment: @Andy If your code works can you please post it?

Comment: My test harness does some other stuff as well. But here's how to do it ( and learn ). Extract the template for a combobox. Put one on a window. Select it then in the property window scroll down to Miscellaneous. Click the square over on the right from Template and choose add as resource. Bam you have a huge swathe of XAML in your window. Search that for popup. This is the thing that appears with your list of options in it. That has a Placement="Bottom". Change that to "Top". Done. Give it a twirl.

Comment: You will find on win10 you need to add a reference to PresentationFramework.Aero2 to you project, by the way.